# Where does Gazebo set the GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH environment variable?

Tags: gazebo

I'm starting out with Gazebo (1.5) at the moment and am following [a tutorial](http://bramridder.com/ai-blog.php/integrating-ros-with-gazebo) off the internet. In order to get Gazebo to find the model, the author advocates manually exporting the `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` environment variable via

```
export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=[...]/models:$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH
```

But that will only work for the current terminal. So I wanted to change the environment variable permanently.

The [Gazebo User Guide](http://gazebosim.org/user_guide/started__components__env.html) claims that `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH`, along with all the other environment variables, is set by `/usr/share/gazebo-1.5/setup.sh` but my (virgin) Gazebo install doesn't list it:

```
export GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11345
export GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_URI=http://gazebosim.org/models
export GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/share/gazebo-1.5:/usr/share/gazebo_models
export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/gazebo-1.5/plugins
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gazebo-1.5/plugins:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.7.4

# This line is needed while we're relying on ROS's urdfdom library
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

But when I start Gazebo, `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` is already set to `$HOME/.gazebo/models`, so it must be set somewhere. I guess I could probably simply add `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` to the `setup.sh` script, but since it is set somewhere, I'd still like to know where and whether it is better practice to set it in there.

Comment: The answer by @Armin Meisterhirn should be marked as an answer IMO. Btw, Gazebo has its own QA forum http://answers.gazebosim.org/

Answer (score 10):

This is more of a Linux than a Gazebo problem. You can just add this line

```
export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=[...]/models:$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH
```

to your *~/.bashrc* file.

Answer (score 4):

You asked two questions.

1. Where does Gazebo set the default model path
2. Where should I set the value

The second question is perfectly right answered by @Armin Meisterhirn. Best practice is to set the variable in the .bashrc file.

The first question, I asked myself as well when starting working with gazebo.

In case of the pure Gazebo (no roslaunch, no plugins) the answer is as simple as that:

In the source code. Gazebo always sets an additional path which is the default value.

Look [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/ec2881681a3e1b075cf512f83ea39ad2c356cdce/gazebo/common/SystemPaths.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

Line 84:

```
this->modelPaths.push_back(home + "/.gazebo/models");
```

As a result, you always have a default path, whatever you do (except you change the source code).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just setting Gazebo path did not solved the issue. Running `roscore`, in  a separate terminal, solved my problem.